# how to pass variable from python to shell script when shell script is getting called inside python script

Tags: python, bash, shell

Scenario:

i have one python scrips called `bc4j.py` which have one global variable

```
correctBc4jfiles = []
```

This variable contains the list of all the files

Now i want to call another shell script such as `mail.sh` inside this python script and in that shell script

1. I want to know the number of files the `correctBc4jfiles` variable holds
2. I want to iterate this variable correctBc4jfiles. how will i iterate it in shell script.
3. I want to assign the value of the `correctBc4jfiles` variable into another array variable which belongs to the shell script itself.
4. Can we pass more than one variable from python to shell script? Like in this case we are passing only one variable `correctBc4jfiles`? How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: `subprocess.call(['./mail.sh'] + correctBc4jfiles)` then bash away at the command line args

Comment: it's not working even it is not calling the file as well.

Comment: does it find it if you do `subprocess.call(['./mail.sh'] + correctBc4jfiles, shell=True)`

Answer (score 1):

For passing only one argument, you can have a python script like this:

```
import subprocess
correctBc4jfiles = ["1","2","3"]
subprocess.call(["/bin/bash", "/path/to/mail.sh"] + correctBc4jfiles)
```

And have a bash script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# I want to know the number of files the correctBc4jfiles variable holds

echo "$#"

# I want to iterate this variable correctBc4jfiles. how will i iterate it in shell script.

for A in "$@"; do
    echo "$A"
done

# I want to assign the value of the correctBc4jfiles variable into another array variable which belongs to the shell script itself.

ANOTHER=("${@}")

# for A in "${ANOTHER[@]}"; do ...
```

*Can we pass more than one variable from python to shell script? Like in this case we are passing only one variable correctBc4jfiles? How can I do this?*

You have to make your python script pass the number of values for every variable as well like:

```
import subprocess

var0 = ["|1|", "|2|", "|3|"]
var1 = ["|4|", "|5|", "|6|"]

subprocess.call(["/bin/bash", "script.sh"] + [str(len(var0))] + var0 + [str(len(var1))] + var1)
```

And let bash interpret it:

```
#!/bin/bash

varprefix='var'
varindex=0

declare -i  count

while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
    count=$1
    if [[ count -gt 0 ]]; then
        eval "${varprefix}$(( varindex++ ))=(\"\${@:2:count}\")"
        shift "$count"
    fi
    shift
done

set | grep ^var  ## Just show what variables were made.
```

It gives an output like this:

```
var0=([0]="|1|" [1]="|2|" [2]="|3|")
var1=([0]="|4|" [1]="|5|" [2]="|6|")
varindex=2
varprefix=var
```

So with that you could already use varX.

If you don't like the varX format, you could just copy the values to desired array variable:

```
myarray1=("${var0[@]}")
myarray2=("${var1[@]}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- Step through the list, and then call `mail.sh` once for each file. This is the most reliable way.
- Convert the items in the list to a space delimited string, and then pass it in to `mail.sh` (assuming `mail.sh` is setup correctly, it should accept multiple arguments).

What you cannot do is pass `['a.txt','b.txt','c.txt']` wholesale to the script.

Comment: i already tried but not working.... can you please give me clear idea on how to do it as i want to perform 4 action mentioned above